# how to use webview on appwidgetprovider

Tags: android

i need to use **web view** on widget android programming but i don't know how it works.
i used it on MainActivity but it does not work with widget!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String url = "http://google.com/";
        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to use webview on appwidgetprovider

`WebView` is not one of [the supported widgets for use in an app widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).

Comment: @user3640616: "is there any another solution ? " -- not really. You are welcome to try parsing some HTML with `Html.fromHtml()` and using that with `setTextViewText()` to apply some light formatting. However, `Html.fromHtml()` does not support a lot of Web content (CSS, JavaScript, `iframe`, bulleted/numbered lists, etc.).